# Outlook Addin API body.getAsync missing some styles on mac

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync() on mac misses certain styles, such as bullet points.

Details:

- CoercionType.Html is used.
- Only occurs on Outlook for Mac client, not on OWA.
- Outlook for Mac Version 16.13 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.
- To reproduce, insert bullets into the message body using the client UI:

> `• Testing bullets`

- Call getAsync with coercion type HTML and expect the following:

> `<p class=MsoListParagraph style='text-indent:0in'>Testing bullets</p>`

- Call setAsync with the above HTML and expect the bullet to disappear

---

Notes: I understand the documentation indicates:

> Body.getAsync and Body.setAsync methods are not idempotent.

But the bullet is inserted from the Outlook UI itself and I expect the API to fully support it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be inserting as HTML unordered list elements, not a styled paragraph:

```js
Word.run(function(context) {
  var body = context.document.body;
  body.insertHtml("<ul><li>Testing Bullet 1</li><li>Testing Bullet 2</li></ul>", Word.InsertLocation.start);
  return context.sync();
});
```

Comment: @mlafleur I should've been more specific. The bullet is inserted from the client UI by the user, not programmatically. I'll update the post.

Comment: Thanks for raising it. we are working towards fixing it and update the thread.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility any updates?